# Can't enable integrated webcam with function keys or via BIOS

Tags: shortcut-keys, skype, webcam

I'm on 14.04 and I can't activate the integrated webcam on my **Medion Akoya P6630** laptop. Usually, this is done with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, but this does not work. Other function key combinations (Sleep, Brightness, Volume, ...) work, though.

This is a dual boot installation. However, I can't enable the camera inside Windows, since the harddrive/partition is toast. The camera is listed as `LAST STATE` in my BIOS. The other option is `DISABLED`. That means I can't enable it from there, either.

Neither Cheese nor Skype recognize a webcam device. Are there other ways I could try to enable the webcam?

**What else did I try:**

- Setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi="` in `/etc/default/grub`
- `lsb_release -a; uname -a; lsusb`:

```
user@MACHINE:~$ lsb_release -a; uname -a; lsusb
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
Linux MACHINE 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bus 002 Device 004: ID e0ff:0002  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

2 possibilities if you cannot enable the webcam under windows and do not have the exact model number of the webcam: (no, the brand of the laptop doesn't count: we need the brand/model of the webcam itself)

Before you choose one of the solutions, take pictures of all your BIOS screens (or painstakingly write them on a piece of paper, or if you have an IBM-compatible printer, just take a print screen of all the BIOS screens)

1. Upgrade your BIOS.
2. Reset BIOS to default factory settings

and then put your BIOS settings back to where they were before doing this, taking care not to touch the webcam settings...

The other possibility (if the above doesn't work and not a software solution) is:

3. buy a Linux-compatible webcam.

Comment: What is the expected output for upgrading or resetting the BIOS? Are you implying the internal state of the webcam is _enabled_ on factory settings?

Comment: Upgrading the BIOS to have an "enable on boot" and the reset to factory settings to hopefully have a kick in the lower abdomen to allow it to work.  I give go a 50% chance on the first and a 25% chance on the second...  No certainties here, but the best I can do giving the circumstances...

Comment: @kleinfreund: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**